# Creating a single var for a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

i am trying to get my list of tags but using a foreach so that i can put each tag into a list element.

What i used to do was:

```
$tagsArray = "these,are,some,tags"

// Explode the tags
$tagsArray = explode(",",$tags);

<ul>
<?php
// Create a list for the tags
foreach($tagsArray as $var)
{
  echo "<li>$var</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

However, i now need to display this array inside an echo as well as other items.

Example:

```
<?php
echo "
  <div id='editInfomation'>
    <div id='Title'>This is a title</div>
    <div id='tags'>
      <ul>$tags</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
";
?>
```

How should i create a $tags variable that will contain all the exploded tags but in list element tags? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need.

```
$tagsArray = "these,are,some,tags";      
$tags = "<li>".implode("</li>,<li>",explode(",",$tagsArray ))."</li>";
```

And you simply print

```
<?php
echo "
  <div id='editInfomation'>
    <div id='Title'>This is a title</div>
    <div id='tags'>
      <ul>$tags</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure on what you're asking, but:

> How should i create a $tags variable that will contain all the exploded tags but in list element tags?

You can push each element into an array, formatted:

```
$output = array();
foreach($tagsArray as $var) {
    $output[] = "<li>$var</li>";
}
```

... then:

```
echo "<ul>" . implode($output) . "</ul>";
```